# Training one agent in multiple CPU-cores

Tags: multiprocessing, reinforcement-learning, openai-api

As a beginner in OpenAI gymnasium, my goal is build SAC from scratch and use it to train an agent on Bipedalwalker problem. I attempt to use `gym.vector.SyncVectorEn` in order to use *multiprocessing* option on CPU available in this gym.

I am unsure how to assign a processor to process each observation? nor how I would combine the learning together? can you give me some directions?